# Calling "set" command within vim custom command

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a custom command in Vim to make setting the makeprg variable for an out-of-source build easier. Having read the command manual, so far I've got as far as this

```
command! -complete=file -nargs=1 Cmakeprg call set makeprg=cmake --build <args><CR>
```

but it isn't working. How do I call "set" within the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `:call` *functions*, `:set` is an *Ex command* just like `:call` (as it's invoked with the `:` prefix).

A complication with `:set` is that whitespace must be escaped with `\`, but that can be avoided by using `:let` with the `&option`, and `<q-args>` automatically quotes the passed command arguments.

You also don't need `<CR>`; this isn't a mapping. Taken all together:

```
command! -complete=file -nargs=1 Cmakeprg let &makeprg = 'cmake --build ' . <q-args>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a colon in front of "set" and use a `<CR>` to execute it: `:set … <CR>`

Do not use `call`.